# Is there any program that listen javascript codes from a website?

Tags: php, javascript

I working on php and I am a newbie about php. I want to see which code is running when i click a button on a gridview. Is there any program that can do this ?

I want to js codes that are working. I have js codes but it is very complicated. I just want to see when i click a button on the gridview which part of codes are working.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information and an example?

Comment: Do you want to listen to Javascript code or to PHP code?

Comment: I want to js codes that are working. I have js codes but it is very complicated. I just want to see when i click a button on the gridview which part of codes are working.

Comment: You may get some mileage out of a JS profiler (Chrome dev tools has one built in). A CPU profiler will show active parts of your code, which may help you narrow it down if you do, in fact, have a lot of code. I maintain JS apps with >6000 SLOC, but I haven't found this necessary, so maybe it's a bit overkill for your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use chrome you can open the developer tools (F12), go to the sources tab. On the right side you add the breakpoints you want, in this case it would be under the `Event Listener Breakpoints` accordion. Then under the `Mouse` dropdown, select `click`. Now you have breakpoints every time click events happen and you can use the buttons on the top or `F10, F11, shift + F11` to continue execution of the code.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server, the button clicked is client, so there is no way of PHP knowing which button you clicked, unless you inform it by some sort of request. But you can still track your clicks on clientside for testing purposes by the developer tools integrated in all the browsers. In chrome for example press CTRL+SHIFT+i

Comment: exactly. another good tool is the firefox plugin "firebug". If you want to work longterm with JS, maybe a javascript IDE like aptana would be worth it

Comment: You are of course right folks, it was just an example. Most browsers provide similar tools. There are pros and cons to all of them and often it's a matter of personal taste.